# WebView doesn't work when implement my own Application Class

Tags: android, webview, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

Hi I have an awkward error when I implement my own Application class like

```
   public class ApplicationController extends Application{
   .....
```

and put entry in android manifest like

```
    <application
        android:name="com.mypackage.ApplicationController"
        ...
```

everything working fine except layout with `WebView` not working. It throws an exception on `setContentView()`:

```
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #104: Error inflating class android.webkit.WebView
```

Thanks

Comment: you need to extend from Activity

Comment: <application
        adnroid:name="com.mypackage.ApplicationController".............Please check  your spelling. Its android:name

Comment: @Rashmi.B there is no spelling mistake in my project its jst typing mistake here.

Comment: Can you paste the XML for your WebView's Activity's layout?

Comment: there is only webview in linearlayout...

Answer (score 0):

You cannot set a content view to a class extending an `Application` class. You can do that from an `Activity`. Either change this class to extend `Activity` or create another one that extends `Activity`.